# How to compare the upper double-precision floating-point element with SSE

Tags: c, intel, sse, simd, intrinsics

I am finding a way to compare the upper part between two __m128d variable.
So I look up https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/ for relative intrinsics.

But I only can find some intrinsics comparing the **lower part** between two variable, for example, `_mm_comieq_sd`.

I am wonder why there is not intrinsics about comparing the upper part, and more importantly, how to compare the upper part between two __m128d variable?

---

Update:

The code is like

```
    j0     =  jprev0;
    j1     =  jprev1;

    t_0    =  p_i_x - pj_x_0;
    t_1    =  p_i_x - pj_x_1;
    r2_0   =  t_0 * t_0;
    r2_1   =  t_1 * t_1;

    t_0    =  p_i_y - pj_y_0;
    t_1    =  p_i_y - pj_y_1;
    r2_0  +=  t_0 * t_0;
    r2_1  +=  t_1 * t_1;

    t_0    =  p_i_z - pj_z_0;
    t_1    =  p_i_z - pj_z_1;
    r2_0  +=  t_0 * t_0;
    r2_1  +=  t_1 * t_1;

    #if NAMD_ComputeNonbonded_SortAtoms != 0 && ( 0 PAIR ( + 1 ) )
    sortEntry0 = sortValues + g; 
    sortEntry1 = sortValues + g + 1; 
    jprev0 = sortEntry0->index;
    jprev1 = sortEntry1->index;
    #else
    jprev0     =  glist[g  ];
    jprev1     =  glist[g+1];
    #endif

    pj_x_0     =  p_1[jprev0].position.x;
    pj_x_1     =  p_1[jprev1].position.x;
    pj_y_0     =  p_1[jprev0].position.y; 
    pj_y_1     =  p_1[jprev1].position.y;
    pj_z_0     =  p_1[jprev0].position.z; 
    pj_z_1     =  p_1[jprev1].position.z;

    // want to use sse to compare those
    bool test0 = ( r2_0 < groupplcutoff2 );
    bool test1 = ( r2_1 < groupplcutoff2 );

    //removing ifs benefits on many architectures
    //as the extra stores will only warm the cache up
    goodglist [ hu         ] = j0;
    goodglist [ hu + test0 ] = j1;

    hu += test0 + test1;
```

And I am trying to rewrite it with SSE.

Comment: Why not do a packed compare and only use the result of the top comparison?

Comment: @Mysticial It is my plan B :)

Comment: There are several ways of doing this (e.g. `_mm_comieq_sd(_mm_shuffle_ps(x,x,0xee))`) but your question would probably be more interesting if you showed what you're trying to do. Probably there is more efficient way than what you're doing now.

Comment: @Mysticial, I just noticed that the original tag was SSE then you changed it to SSE2 and now I have changed it back to SSE. I see the SSE tag as a general tag covering SSE-SSE4.2. The SSE2 tag only has 10% of questions as SSE. But I also trust your judgment more than mine. Should I have left this as SSE2?

Comment: @Zboson Oh, I changed it to SSE2 because SSE doesn't have double precision which is what the OP is asking about. I don't feel particularly strongly about it though. The SSE tags are a mess anyway.

Comment: @Zboson `shuffle` is a good idea, thank you. I will try it once I go back to work.

Comment: @罗泽轩, the code you added is not helpful. What are you doing overall? Why must you compare only the upper part of the SSE register?

Comment: @Zboson Oh, currently I am optimizing a program. The former code use two double variable(a, b) and compare it with another two double variable(c, d), and store the result in test0/test1. During optimization, I pack a, b and c, d into __m128d, so I look for a way to compare both lower part and upper part, like comparing a with c and comparing b with d.

Comment: Can you add your scalar code you used before optimized with SSE?

Comment: @Zboson I update the code before optimized now. Sorry to take your time.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking how to compare upper halves after already having compared the lower halves.

The SIMD way to do compares is with a packed compare instruction, like  `__m128d _mm_cmplt_pd (__m128d a, __m128d b)`, which produces a mask as an output instead of setting flags.  AVX has an improved `vcmppd / vcmpps` which has a wider choice of compare operators, which you pass as a 3rd arg.  `_mm_cmp_pd (__m128d a, __m128d b, const int imm8)`.

```
const __m128d groupplcutoff2_vec = _mm_broadcastsd_pd(groupplcutoff2);
// should emit SSE3 movddup like _mm_movedup_pd() would.

__m128d r2 = ...;

// bool test0 = ( r2_0 < groupplcutoff2 );
// bool test1 = ( r2_1 < groupplcutoff2 );
__m128d ltvec = _mm_cmplt_pd(r2, groupplcutoff2_vec);
int ltmask = _mm_movemask_pd(ltvec);

bool test0 = ltmask & 1;
// bool test1 = ltmask & 2;

// assuming j is double.  I'm not sure from your code, it might be int.
// and you're right, doing both stores unconditionally is prob. fastest, if your code isn't heavy on stores.
// goodglist [ hu         ] = j0;
_mm_store_sd (goodglist [ hu         ], j);
// goodglist [ hu + test0 ] = j1;
_mm_storeh_pd(goodglist [ hu + test0 ], j);
// don't try to use non-AVX _mm_maskmoveu_si128, it's like movnt.  And doesn't do exactly what this needs, anyway, without shuffling j and ltvec.

// hu += test0 + test1;
hu += _popcnt32(ltmask);  // Nehalem or later.  Check the popcnt CPUID flag
```

The popcnt trick will work just as efficiently with AVX (4 doubles packed in a ymm register).  Packed-compare -> movemask and using bit manipulation is a useful trick to keep in mind.